Autodesk forge js viewer load multiple windows position not right
We are trying to load two models. These two models are split from one large model. 
However, we cannot restore their positions correctly using autodesk js viewer, but autodesk acc model coordination can.
urns.map((m)=>{
      Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(`urn:${m.urn}`, (doc) => {
        let viewables = doc.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
        let viewerConf = {
          keepCurrentModels: true,
        }

        this.viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, viewables, viewerConf).then(() => console.log('multiple model loaded'));
      })
    })

Can anyone provide any helpful information?
Autodesk Acc Model Coordination 
Our Attempt
We tried the method in the document (above), but it didn’t work

Could you please refer to this blog -  https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/loading-multiple-models-forge-viewer-v7
Code pen set up - https://codepen.io/autodesk-platform-services/pen/bGQQEdV
import { initViewer } from "https://aps-codepen.autodesk.io/utils.js";

function addViewable(viewer, urn, xform, offset) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    function onDocumentLoadSuccess(doc) {
      const viewable = doc.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
      const options = {
        //  preserveView: true,
        keepCurrentModels: true
      };
      if (xform) {
        options.placementTransform = xform;
      }
      if (offset) {
        options.globalOffset = offset;
      }
      viewer
        .loadDocumentNode(doc, viewable, options)
        .then(resolve)
        .catch(reject);
    }
    function onDocumentLoadFailure(code) {
      reject(`Could not load document (${code}).`);
    }
    Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(
      "urn:" + urn,
      onDocumentLoadSuccess,
      onDocumentLoadFailure
    );
  });
}

const viewer = await initViewer(document.getElementById("viewer"), {
  extensions: ["Autodesk.DocumentBrowser"]
});

await addViewable(
  viewer,
  "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YXBzLWNvZGVwZW4tYmFja2VuZC8wMV9yYWNfYmFzaWNfc2FtcGxlX3Byb2plY3QucnZ0"
);

await addViewable(
  viewer,      
  //"dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YXBzLWNvZGVwZW4tYmFja2VuZC8wMl9qZXRfZW5naW5lX21vZGVsLnppcA",
  "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YXBzLWNvZGVwZW4tYmFja2VuZC8wNV9zcGFjZXNoaXAuZjNk",
  new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX(0.5 * Math.PI).scale(new THREE.Vector3(2.5, 2.5, 2.5))
);


In my case, both models were loaded normally, but the relative positions of the models were incorrect. They were originally split from the same large model.Just like shown in the above picture
